# Problem-solving approach to Classical Mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations

I'm looking for a book with problem-solving approach to the intermediate classical mechanics. The book I expect should have:

1. Solutions to all of its problems
2. Be Calculus based(!) - try to show me the way to solve the problem with integration techniques or using differential equations, even much more advanced material.
3. Give clear definition of concepts and no  more fluff, going to solve the problems straightforward.
4. Keep me focused on the problems rather than the amount of text remained to be read.

To put it in a nutshell, I don't want a book with bunch of useless text, I want something to help me go through problems.
It would be really helpful to introduce the topics which are alike this topic.Moderators only specialty is to close topics for fun and profit.

Comment: While there are many books with bunches of useless text, it is worth noting that just showing how to solve problems is no substitute for acquiring a conceptual understanding of *physics* (which is not only knowing the concepts to solve *physics problems*), which is necessarily transmitted through text.

Comment: I can't give you an appropriate answer, but I think what you are asking for is a mindless text that won't allow you to learn anything about physics, whatsoever.

Comment: @CuriousOne What I said didn't imply that I hate or don't want to read a book with explanation! what I said means that I'm looking for a book with problem-solving approach.It would rather be better not to comment than commenting useless text.No insult.

Comment: Your criteria would clearly eliminate Landau/Lifshitz Volume 1 on classical mechanics, which in my mind is one of the best scientific textbooks that were ever written. The intellectual clarity and consistency of the "useless text" in that book, that you care so little about, is absolutely stunning. I don't know what makes you think that physics is about textbook problem solving. It's not even close to that.

Comment: @CuriousOne Who said "Physics is about textbook problem solving" ? at least I didn't, what I asked for was a textbook full of problems with no extra text, are you near me to know whether I read other textbooks or not?how's that you judge so fast?! - Although I know Lifshitz- I gave +1

Comment: Hi FreeMind. Resource-recommendations questions (RRQs) are tightly regulated on Phys.SE. There are already many RRQs on Classical Mechanics. I close it as a _duplicate,_ not because it is necessarily an exact duplicate, but to point in the right direction.

Comment: I don't agree with the decision of close this question. Is true there are other questions about books of classical mechanics, but none of them say something about a problem based book. I really want to know if there is such a texbook, it'll be a great resourse to learn classical mechanics. In particular i could't find a book with such an aproach in the given link.

Comment: @Héctor: Even if there was such a book (I am sure there is), it's not in the best interest of the OP to read it. It would certainly not be good advice from anybody to direct a student of physics to such a book who seems to have a very skewed opinion about the topic, already.

Comment: @CuriousOne I don't know why you think that someone who asks for the problem-solving based physics book has a skewed opinion about the topic, you even can't explain why you have such idea.

Comment: @FreeMind: "To put it in a nutshell, I don't want a book with bunch of useless text" is your choice of words, not mine. Feel free to correct your statement.

Comment: @CuriousOne That doesn't mean I've got skewed opinion about physics, watch your hands while typing, you insult people easily without any rationale behind it.

Comment: @FreeMind: You are, again, free to revise what you said.